# Pass specific 'state' Selection from one object to another - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have these models:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
            if vals.get('production_type') == 'budgeted':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.budgeted') or '/'
            elif vals.get('production_type') == 'nonbudgeted':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.non_budgeted') or '/'
            elif vals.get('production_type') == 'direct':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.direct') or '/'
        return super(bsi_production_order, self).create(vals)

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
    production_type = fields.Selection([
        ('budgeted','Budgeted'),
        ('nonbudgeted','Non Budgeted'),
        ('direct','Direct Order'),
    ], string='Type of Order', index=True,  
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.production.order.lines', 'production_order', states={'finished': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, string="Order lines", copy=True)
print_orders = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Orders")
state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('start','Started'),
        ('inprogress','In progress'),
        ('print_order_inprogress','Print Order In Progress'),
        ('finished','Finished'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string='State', index=True,  
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")

class bsi_print_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
            vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.print.order') or '/'
        return super(bsi_print_order, self).create(vals)

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Print Date")
    origin = fields.Char(string="Origin")
    production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order.lines', 'print_order', string="Order lines")
    book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Book Block")
    binding = fields.Boolean(string="Binding")
    edging = fields.Boolean(string="Edging")
    contract_worksheet = fields.One2many('mrp.worksheet.contract', 'printer_order', string="Worksheet calculation")
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('awaitingraw','Awaiting raw materials'),
        ('wip','Work in Progress'),
        ('delivered','Delivered'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string="State")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
```

And this method, which belongs to `bsi.production.order` , it has to create a `bsi.print.order` from it:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['bsi.print.order'] 
    for record in self:

        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'isbn': rec.isbn.id,
                'consumed_qty': rec.qty,
                }
            ))

        copy_record.create({
            'state' : 'draft', 
            'order_lines': order_lines, 
        })
```

What is the problem? The problem is that, on `bsi.production.order` the state from which this function is visible (the button) is `inprogress`, now, this state doesn't exist on `bsi.print.order`, but, as You can see, on `copy_record.create`, I've passed 'state' as 'draft', but it doesn't works, it throws me:

```
ValidateError

Error while validating constraint

Wrong value for bsi.print.order.state: 'inprogress'
```

I mean, it's obvious, but not so much, because the `bsi.print.order` should be created on `draft` state.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a compute field somewhere that changed the state in your code

Comment: I've noted that when I add the 'order_lines' field on the bsi.production.order, then this happens, mmm

Comment: I wonder if the fact that both One2many fields (order_lines) are called the same of both models, could that be the reason behind this?

Comment: consumed_qty is a computed field yes, but?

Comment: If it is a computed field you mustn't assign any value to it directly. The compute method that you have assigned to the field is the responsible for it.

Comment: How can I do this then? I mean, I need to pass that computed field somehow

Comment: Hi, I've tried without computed fields, and it's the same situation, I don't know what else to do

Comment: The issue starts when I do add the isbn field, the actual One2many

Comment: Also, when I create this object, the original one is on 'inprogress' state. I've changed the fields to be non-computed, but same result... Idk